# How to display something in the web page when downloading file in Django

Tags: django

I am very very new to Django and i am getting my feet wet with it. I have a use case in which i want the user to download a file when they go to the home page of the Django website but at the same time i want to show some text as well.

Below is the definition of my view:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse


def home(request):
    my_data = "<h1>This will be an attachement to download!</h1>"
    response = HttpResponse()
    response.content = my_data
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="<some-file>"'
    return response
```

The issue is the file is getting downloaded but i cannot see anything getting printed to the screen . I mean i need this message (

## This will be an attachement to download!

) to also be in the screen . I am sure i am doing some simple mistake but i cannot figure out what it is.

Can someone please help me.

Comment: To display a new message on an already opened HTML page you should use JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be doing this with the backend, instead add an event listener that triggers a [`confirm`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp):

```
$('#download_button_id').on('click', function(e) {
  if (!confirm('This will be an attachment to download!')) {
    e.preventDefault();
  };
});
```

Now, when a user tries to push the download button, a dialog box pops up that shows the message with confirm/cancel buttons, and if cancel is pushed, `e.preventDefault()` triggers.

Comment: I thought this is possible to do in Django. Thanks anyways :)